# Wicket invalidate cached pages

Tags: java, wicket

I'm make a custom resource loader which loads resource properties from database. Those properties can be changed by some user of the application but changes doesn't affect because all the pages are cached in that locale so I need to make them invalid. If you have any suggestion about direction where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See org.apache.wicket.settings.IMarkupSettings.getMarkupCache(), org.apache.wicket.markup.IMarkupCache.removeMarkup(String).

Comment: I try that but doesn't work :(. getApplication().getMarkupSettings().getMarkupCache().clear(); the page localization properties stays cached.